# Is it possible to use (preferably empty) range specification with empty HTTP entity?

Tags: http, amazon-s3, http-headers

**Situation:**

- HTTP entity (S3 object in my case)
- GET request returns additional information (`x-amz-tagging-count`) that I need

  - note: unfortunately equivalent HEAD request doesn't return that info
- to get that info GET request is sent with a small range specification (e.g. `Range:0-0`)

**Problems:**

- we retrieve unnecessary data (with performance hit: time server spends to read that byte)
- it fails for zero-sized entities (S3 objects)

Related parts from [HTTP 1.1 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233.html#page-5):

```
    first-byte-pos  = 1*DIGIT
    last-byte-pos   = 1*DIGIT
    byte-range-spec = first-byte-pos "-" [ last-byte-pos ]
    ...
   A byte-range-spec is invalid if the last-byte-pos value is present
   and less than the first-byte-pos.
    ...
    suffix-length = 1*DIGIT
    suffix-byte-range-spec = "-" suffix-length
    ...
   If the selected representation is shorter than the specified
   suffix-length, the entire representation is used.
    ...
   If a valid byte-range-set includes at least one byte-range-spec with
   a first-byte-pos that is less(!!) than the current length of the
   representation, or at least one suffix-byte-range-spec with a
   non-zero(!!) suffix-length, then the byte-range-set is satisfiable.
   Otherwise, the byte-range-set is unsatisfiable.
```

It seems to me that:

1. it is impossible to specify empty range at all (i.e. `1-0` and `-0` are both `invalid` or `unsatisfiable`)
2. if entity length is zero -- `Range:-1` **should** work (and return 0 bytes) according to the standard, but each server I tried (including AWS S3) was failing with "invalid range" message

**Question:**

What is the best way to deal with this situation? (ideally, I'd like to specify an empty range)

**Notes:**

- I can omit range specifier for empty entities, but this creates a race condition -- it is possible for entity to be updated right before my GET request and I will end up downloading potentially huge amount of data

Comment: Have you tried `Range: bytes=0-` yet? IE, omit the `last-byte-pos` since it is *optional*.  However, you might consider reporting the missing `x-amz-tagging-count` header in `HEAD` as a bug to Amazon, since `HEAD` is *supposed* to return all of the same headers that `GET` returns, just omitting the response body.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `0-` would give me entire entity :-). Reporting a bug won't fix existing implementations (AWS S3, StorageGrid, etc) :-\

Comment: "*`0-` would give me entire entity*" - ah, good point. Well, then, you are basically out of luck. Reading the spec more closely, it seems 0-length ranges are simply not valid. So you are stuck with `0-0` for non-empty entities. I don't see any way to ask for a valid range on an empty entity, so you will likely have to use `HEAD` first to see if the entity is empty or not, and then send `GET` with a `Range` only if not empty. But like you said, that would introduce a race condition. Fortunately, *Conditional-GET* requests can handle that, so you can detect a modification and start over.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `Range:-1` is supposed to work, but implementations failed to support this. :-/ Can you elaborate on _Conditional-GET_, please? I've never heard about it...

Comment: see [HTTP conditional requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Conditional_requests), and more formally [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232.html)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Huh... I can't use `etag` matching since it doesn't guarantee uniqueness. I can use `If-Unmodified-Since` but only if my process delays processing of entities until they are "old enough" (because this timestamp has 1 second resolution). Plus server needs to "behave" -- i.e. whenever a change to `mdate` is made, new timestamp should be "recent enough" (and it's clock needs to be "reasonably in sync" with client). This should work... Thanks! (note: server clock shouldn't jump around too -- needs some sort of a guarantee here)

Comment: "*I can't use `etag` matching since it doesn't guarantee uniqueness*" - yes, it does. If an entity is changed, a new ETag is generated for it. When you request an entity for the first time, save its current ETag. Next time you want to request the same entity again, send the saved ETag. If it still matches, the entity hasn't been changed, otherwise it has changed, so start over. So, cin your case, send a `HEAD` request to get the entity's size and ETag, then `GET` the entity specifying the ETag. You will either get the same entity with latest headers, or you won't get the entity at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, you can't build a hashing scheme that guarantees lack of collisions (unless your hash size is >= original data size). In S3 (unless object was uploaded via MultipartUpload) etag is an md5 sum of object data. It is trivial to come up with an update that will leave etag unchanged.

Comment: While it is *possibly* for MD5 to have collisions, the chances of it happening are astronomically small. And besides, ETags are per-entity, so two entities can have the same ETag as long as they have different URLs. But regarding S3 specifically, an ETag is not always an MD5 hash. See [How can I check the integrity of an object uploaded to Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/)

Comment: In any case, a conditional-GET can have multiple conditions, so even if the ETag hasn't changed, its modification date will. You can check both. The chances of an entity being altered between a HEAD and GET while maintaining the same modification date AND ETag are almost impossible

Comment: :-) from my pov code is either correct or not. And correct means "works always", not in 99.99999% of cases. In any case, thanks for pointers

Comment: @RemyLebeau `... the chances of it happening are astronomically small`. Lol, look [what I've found](https://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to standard the only way to specify a *satisfiable* for empty entity range is to use `suffix-byte-range-spec` with non-zero `suffix-length` (i.e. `Range:-1`, `Range:-2`, etc).

Unfortunately, none of servers I checked (AWS, StorageGrid, Dell ECS) support this.

Therefore to avoid races the only solution is:

- to use *conditional* GET with condition on timestamp
- structure your logic in such way that entities with too early timestamps are ignored

  - i.e. have a "dead" window (X-seconds-ago, +inf) where objects (with timestamp in that window) are ignored
- have your logic executed repeatedly (incrementally?) until final run
- make sure final run is executed in environment where data is guaranteed to not change
- make sure server's clock is "reasonably" synchronized with clients (i.e. drift is well within aforementioned time window)

Alternatively, condition can use `etag`, but I wouldn't do it to avoid race in case of md5 collision. Which [isn't particularly hard](https://www.mscs.dal.ca/%7Eselinger/md5collision/) to achieve...

In case of S3 another alternative is to use versioned buckets and execute GET on specific object version.